# blank terminal and default theme is lost in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Accidentally lost my default Ubuntu theme and the gnome terminal become blank. Please help me to restore my old Ubuntu setting.its very urgent.Pls help

Comment: try to reset unity and compiz.

Comment: thanks for the response.but i don't know how to reset it.pls help

Comment: login into virtual console(ctrl+alt+F1) then run `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` before doing that,dont forget to install dconf by running `sudo apt-get install dconf`.

Comment: frnd..can u explain why happening like this in my system???

Answer (score 0):

Log in to a tty (press Ctrl+Alt+F1 for tty1, Ctrl+Alt+F2 for tty2 and tty7 is for login screen/desktop) 
and type your username, and enter and type in your password. Nothing will show up in the password field as a security feature.
At the prompt type in the following to reset all settings:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dconf gconftool
```

(type in your password)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
gconftool --recursive-unset
sudo reboot
```

The next time you log in, it should work again. You will have to change the settings again to have it the same, but stuff (files,apps,themes) should still be  there.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks friends... I done my complaint. I just re-installing the default theme in ubuntu by using:

```
sudo apt-get install light-themes.
```